# How to create a spreadsheet like layout for data table?

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, mysql

I am trying to create a online dashboard which populates all the data from my database into a table and im using javascript datatable plugin for it. But I want to create a better way and want a layout similar to google spreadsheet, in which the spreadsheet tuple can be edited or saved similar to google spreadsheet.

I am using python 2.7, so can someone help me out with this.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not very familiar with mySQL, but I've used [`pandastable`](https://github.com/dmnfarrell/pandastable) for a spreadsheet editor before, if that's what you're looking for. If you're familiar with python's "pandas" dataframe objects, it should be pretty easy to pick up (if not, still not too complicated). You should be able to import/export CSVs into your spreadsheets too. You might have to customize a little bit to get things working the way you want them to.

A more lightweight, barebones version (that doesn't use a pandas dataframe as a backend) is [`tkintertable`](https://github.com/dmnfarrell/tkintertable).

Latest official releases can be installed with `pip install pandastable`, or `pip install tkintertable`.

There's a few examples for both of these in the given links.

Comment: i am looking for something that can be displayed in my website too. Correct me if im wrong, panda is used more for analytics and im looking for more like a spreadsheet functionality in my website

Answer (score 0):

It may be a bit late, but as Anddrw already stated you could use pandas dataframes for this. There is a direct export-to-html function for dataframes. You can style the output and apply conditional formatting with [CSS-like notation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/style.html)

While pandastable focusses on analytics, you can use it to create a simple table to diplay your dataframes. See [this](https://github.com/dmnfarrell/pandastable/wiki/Code-Examples) example in the documentation.

So you could accomplish your tasks uning pandas dataframes and pandastable.

Comment: while this link may answer the question,its better to add some samples